# getch() inside while loop always returns 1

Tags: c++, getch

I'm trying to use "ch" variable after I catch it with getch() function from expression inside a loop. I can't use it at all because it always returns the same char code (1 as int). I know I can just simply use while(1) and make working getch() from there, but it is considered bad practice and I wonder why it just doesn't work this way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    while (char ch = getch() != 'q')
    {
        std::cout << ch;
    }
}
```

I'm using code::blocks 13.12 with GNU GCC Compiler

by the way.. this doesn't work too

```
int main()
{
    char ch;
    while (ch = getch() != 'q')
    {
        std::cout << ch;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)

Comment: general rule of thumb, never put assignment inside conditional

Answer (score 5):

You're running afoul of [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence). It's as if you had written:

```
while (ch = (getch() != 'q'))
```

Which will be `1` until a `q` is entered, at which point it will be `0`.

You mean to say:

```
while ((ch = getch()) != 'q')
```

And, as  [Filipe Gonçalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2793118/filipe-gon%c3%a7alves) mentions, `ch` should be declared as an `int`, not `char` (`getch()` returns an `int`)

Comment: Another issue with the code is that he seems to be declaring `ch` as a `char`, whereas `getch(3)` returns `int`. This should be addressed, and I think it deserves to be mentioned.

Comment: True. More of a concern if he were checking for EOF, but definitely bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, you had wrong order of operations. Either move assignment to right or add parenthesis.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    while ((ch = getch()) != 'q')
    {
        std::cout << ch;
    }
}
```

Note that it's not best idea to declare variable in loop's conditional expression.